# Laravel 5.1 eloquent::attach() method with timestamps

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I seem to have a problem with timestamps - when trying to attach `User` to `Lectures` via `favorites` pivot table - none of the dates updates.

Here's my migration:

```
Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer('lecture_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->primary(['lecture_id', 'user_id']);

});
```

Lecture relationship:

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favorites');
}
```

User relationship:

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Lecture::class, 'favorites')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Whenever I attach:

```
$event->lecture->favorites()->attach($this->user->id);
```

Both fields `created_at` and `updated_at` are set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: In your `belongsToMany` have you tried chaining with `->withTimestamps();` so.. `$this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favourites')->withTimestamps();` ?

Comment: You're absolutely right - I've done it on `User`, but forgotten on `Lecture`. Thanks very much @Phorce - can you post it as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: @Phorce, post your message as an answer, future readers will be benefitted from this :-)

Comment: @seb done this :) if your happy, can you please mark this as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In order to attach the timestamps to each of the model relationships you need to chain the method `->withTimestamps()`.

So, for exam, in your case, it would be the following:

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favorites')->withTimestamps(); 
}
```

This would then attach the timestamps. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks very much @Phorce!